# tensorflow restore variables when batch_size in testing is different from the batch_size in training

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to TensorFlow. I have trained the inception_v3 model successfully with my training data; now I want to predict the output of several images, but the number of them is different from the batch_size in training. I did it as follows:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.slim.nets import inception_v3 as inception
checkpoint_dir =os.path.join('runs', configure_name, 'checkpoints')
checkpoint_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir)
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
      allow_soft_placement=True,
      log_device_placement=False)
    sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
    with sess.as_default():
        # Load the saved meta graph and restore variables
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}.meta".format(checkpoint_file))
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)

        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size,input_size,input_size,num_channels], name='images')
        _, end_points = inception.inception_v3(x,num_classes=num_classes, is_training=False)
        outputs = end_points['Predictions']        

        scores = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={x: x_eval})
        predictions = np.argmax(scores,axis=1)
```

It gave me the errors as follows:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights_1
```

It seems that the model parameters in "outputs" are not fed in successfully, but I do not know how to do it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you explicitly set the first dim of input placeholder x `batch_size`, so each time you need to feed a numpy.array type tensor with the same dim or your program will go wrong.

A solution can be setting the first dim of any placeholder(input and label) `None` so that this dim can be any int or different during training and validation

UPDATE:

if you have already trained your model with a fixed first dim placeholder input(and label), you can change it when restore this graph with `tf.train.import_meta_graph(grapg_def=your_graph_def, input_map={'your_train_input_placedholer_name':new_placeholder})`
here `new_placeholder` is a placeholder you newly create with unfixed first dim.